# Conversion of lists to numpy arrays in cnn

Tags: deep-learning

I have loaded xtrain and ytrain for the cnn but the problem they are lists so i have to convert it into numpy arrays where xtrain represents images and ytrain represents labels?

Answer (score 1):

As you mention that you are working with numpy array, so first **import** the **numpy** package.
I am importing it as **np**.

The function **[asarray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html)** expects the input, in any form that can be converted to an array.

Now all you need to do is, to just pass the list to the function as an input and get the output as an **numpy array**

```
import numpy as np
xtrain_as_array = np.asarray (xtrain_as_list)
ytrain_as_array = np.asarray (ytrain_as_list)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help. A proper explanation [would greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made

Comment: @ShawnC. Thank you for the guidance for provided me. I have added some explanation with the required link. If you find it helpful for others, please upvote it so that the reader/seeker can read and learn from it.